# Adding html to a webview is appearing as blank iOS xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a web view in a Xamarin.forms project and it is populated by some HTML that is loaded from a database.

The following is the XAML code that creates the web view. It may be worth noting that this is inside a GridView.

```
<WebView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="policyView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

And this is the cs code that loads and sets the web view's source so it can display the HTML.

```
     public async void LoadPolicy(policy_procedure policy)
    {
        busyIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        busyMessage.Text = "Loading Policy";

        var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

        htmlSource.Html = await ViewModelLocator.ConvertPolicy(policy);// returns the html as a string

        policyView.Source = htmlSource;

        busyIndicator.IsVisible = false;
    }
```

This code is working fine for Android and is displaying the HTML content without any problem. However, when running on iOS I am just getting a blank screen and I am unsure why this is happening. I have tried setting the horizontal options to `fillAndExpand` likewise with vertical options. My Question is how do I make the HTML code appear on iOS?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use a const html string to test whether it is the method `ConvertPolicy`'s issue. Your webView can be shown on the screen without content or can't be shown?

Comment: Ok Thanks I will try when I am at my computer next thanks.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I tried to use a html string with no luck :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have not given AppTransportSecurity(ATS).
Go to to your info.plist and add the permission.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict> 
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
</dict>
```

for reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have tried this without success. If this was the case would I be getting an error?

Comment: this did not worked for you? It will not give error.

Answer (score 0):

The code below I tested in for iOS. You can adjust it according to your requirement.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Teal" TranslationY="64">
                 <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="Silver" Text="tets test" HeightRequest="30" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <WebView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="webView"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HeightRequest="300"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" /> 
                    </Grid>
                       </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image: webview iOS screenshot]